# $stateprovider doesn't work or show any kind of errors

Tags: angularjs

I can't figure out why my angular state provider doesn't work and it doesn't show no errors. Previously when i used ngRoute everything was working but now when i included `ui.router`nothing seems to work. Previously once i opened application, /#/ link was generated (routed), but now it just hangs on myapp.com/

my HTML index.html

```
   <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>MyApp</title>
        <style type="text/css">
          [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
            display: none !important;
          }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini" ng-app="app">
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
               <div ng-view></div>
        </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
        </div>
        <script src="plugins/angularJs/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="plugins/angularJs/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="plugins/angularJs/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script src="plugins/angularJs/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
        <script src="app/app.js"></script>
        <!-- Controllers  -->
        <script src="app/controllers/locations/locationsCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="app/controllers/dashboard/dashboardCtrl.js"></script>
        <!-- Factories  -->
        <script src="app/factories/locationFactory.js"></script>
        <script src="app/factories/countriesFactory.js"></script>
        <script src="app/factories/provincesFactory.js"></script>
        <!-- Filters  -->
        <script src="app/filters/selectionFilters.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my dashboard.html

```
<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
<section class="content-header">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
    </ol>
</section>
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
    {{data}}
</section>
```

my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
    $stateProvider
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: "/dashboard",
            templateUrl: "app/templates/dashboard/dashboard.html",
            controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
        })
        .state('locations', {
            url: "/locations",
            templateUrl: "app/templates/locations/locations.html",
            controller: 'locationsCtrl'
        })
        .state('/locations/add_location', {
            url: "/locations/add_location",
            templateUrl: "app/templates/locations/add_location.html",
            controller: 'addLocationCtrl'
    });

});
```

Interface and console output
[image: Console]
Loaded files
[image]
I hope you guys know what is going on or what am i missing. If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide.

Comment: Can you show your HTML? (not the scripts in the HTML)

Comment: updated, i hope its enough, otherwise tell me

Comment: Can you directly go to your /dashboard or /locations ?

Comment: the url is changing, but templates or content don't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add

```
<base href="/">
```

in your HTML Head and

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

in your route config.

By the way, use dot syntax  `.` not `/` in state declaration:

```
.state('locations.add_location')
```

---

**Finnally**, replace `<div ng-view></div>` with `<div ui-view></div>` solve the problem.

Comment: maybe replace `<div ng-view></div>` to `<div ui-view></div>`

Comment: this <div ui-view></div> did it, update you answer! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<div ng-view></div>` with `<div ui-view></div>`

Comment: head is closed, i just didn't copy html correctly on stakoverflow